# Is there a way to copy a tab to multiple Google-spreadsheet files at once?

Tags: google-sheets

I have hundreds of Google sheets that I want to add a unified extra tab to them all at once. Instead of copying the tab to an existing sheet ID repeatedly for all IDs, is there a way to tell Google to copy this tab to all of the files of sheets at once (single event)?

Comment: Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: The scenario you describe requires an Apps Script. Start with [Teach yourself Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and [Google Drive Apps documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive).